# php Dropdown Realtime Update

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, drop-down-menu

My apologies if this has been answered before but I did do a search and haven't seen any answers for the questions asked in other posts. The answers I did see didn't relate to my question (mostly to do with dropdowns getting results from mysql).

I have a php dropdown list where you need to select a value (1, 2 or 3). Based on what you select, the list should update a variable and show a hidden div tag. Now from the information I gathered it seems like this cannot be done with php alone but requires a javscript or ajax script.

**php:**

```
<form>
    <select name="options" onchange="{dosomething}">
        <option value="0">[Select value]</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
     </select><br>
</form>
```

This should then update this variable and div in REALTIME:

```
<div id="test" style="display:none">
    $answer= 1 + $value
    <?php
        echo "1 + $value = $answer";
</div>
```

**javascript/ajax:**

```
<script>
    function dosomething {
        #update $value based on dropdown and do calculation
        #unhide div with id "test"  
    }
</script>
```

I need to mention that I have no knowledge of javascript or ajax.

Comment: Include this in the head of your html. <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>. Add an id="options" to your select. Add the following code $("#test").html($( "#options option:selected" ).text())); in your dosomething function and it should work.

Comment: If you use jQuery you can add event listener to the select box using `$('select').on('change', function() {});` Within this function do an ajax call to the server either with `$.ajax`or `$.getJSON`and update and show your div within the callback function.

Comment: Loading an 80KB library for such a simple task really isn't the way to go

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to view the new result in the same page without requesting something to the server add this script below your last div:

```
<script>

var element = document.getElementsByName('options');
if( element.length > 0 ){
    element[0].addEventListener('change',update_text,false);
        //element[0].addEventListener('change',function(){update_text(param)},false);
}

function update_text(evt){
    console.log(evt);
    var first_element = evt.target;
    var selection = first_element.options[first_element.selectedIndex].value;
    //do math:
    selection = +selection + 1; //this cast selection as number and not as String

    console.log(selection);
    var test = document.getElementById('test');
    test.style.display = 'block';
    test.innerHTML = `<p>${selection}</p>`;
};

</script>
```